# Get HTTP Header in WCF MessageEncoder

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http, rest

I'm currently writing a GZIP compression for my selfhosted WCF REST application. I have a custom implementation of the .NET 'MessageEncoder' class and a custom implementation of the 'WebContentTypeMapper' class .

How can I retrieve the http headers in the 'ReadMessage' function and in the 'GetMessageFormatForContentType' function? I'd like to check the incoming request for the 'Content-Encoding' header before decompressing the input.

Thank You.

Comment: Doesn't IIS already provide GZIP compression out of the box ?

Comment: @Alex: My Application needs to run IIS independent in a self hosted scenario

Answer (score 3):

This is what you can do

```
if (WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Content-Encoding"] == WHAT YOU WANT)
{
            // Do what you like to do here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: 'WebOperationContext.Current' seems to be nothing.
In the function 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage' in a self hosted scenario

Answer (score 1):

You could try with WebOperationContext.Current or OperationContext.Current (depending of your binding).
But unfortunately i think you cannot do this within the MessageEncoder implementation itself because it's too late in the process because by the time the MessageEncoder is asked to write the message contents the message frame, in this case the HTTP headers, has already been written. So, you would also need additional behavior, in the form of an IOperationBehavior, applied to your operations that sets the headers accordingly.
In one of my personnal implementation, i have solved this by adding a GzipExtension in OperationContext with a custom message inspector.
As Alex said, IIS already have a feature called dynamic compression that can compression any configured content type.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. I'd like to READ the Http headers.

Comment: @Mimefilt Of course, but you have to add an inspector for reading http headers. Your encoder must not have the content type in the constructor (or something like this). There is a custom encoder in the WCF samples from MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you will be able to get directly to the header from the CustomMessageEncoder. What you may be able to do is leverage the updated .NET 4.5 WCF [BinaryMessageEncoderBindingElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binarymessageencodingbindingelement.aspx). This now allows you to specify the compression type (such as Gzip) and automatically detects if the message body is compressed before attempting to decompress. See [Whats's New in Windows Communication Foundation 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789.aspx) for more details.

If you want to get to the header, one way you could try is to leverage [HttpRequestMessageProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httprequestmessageproperty.aspx) in an implementation of [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.afterreceiverequest.aspx).

Simple example:

```
    public class MyDispatchMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            object obj;
            if (request.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, out obj))
            {
                 var httpRequestMessageProperty = obj as HttpRequestMessageProperty;

                 if (httpRequestMessageProperty != null 
                         && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpRequestMessageProperty.Headers["content-encoding"]))
                 {
                    ...
                 }
            }
            return null;
     }
     ...
}
```

Another option is to access the `OperationContext` using the following:

```
int index = System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.FindHeader("content-encoding", "");
string contentEncodeHeaderValue = System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetHeader<string>(index);
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly 'AfterReceiveRequest' is called after 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage'. 'System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current' is nothing at this point.